# Postfix: How to accept email from a specific non-existing domain?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, domain-name

We need to accept email from a server that sends out using a non-existing domain. That server is not under my control.

In my *main.cf* I have

```
smtpd_client_restrictions       = permit_mynetworks,
                              hash:/etc/postfix/access,
                              permit_sasl_authenticated
```

in /etc/postfix/access I have

```
<server's ip>                 OK
vps1.nonexistingdomain.com         OK
```

However, when I recieve messages from that server in my logs I see:

```
Jul 26 10:30:07 mail3 postfix/smtpd[24044]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from vps1.nonexistingdomain.com[ip address]: 554 5.1.8 <anonymous@vps1.nonexistingdomain.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<anonymous@vps1.nonexistingdomain.com> to=<me@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<vps1.nonexistingdomain.com>
```

As another workaround I tried to manually hardcode this hostname:ip into my /etc/hosts, but that makes no difference.

Comment: You shall not fix other people's failures. Will you always configure _your_ server when _someone else_ is not capable to administer their system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, place the server's IP address in [mynetworks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks).

Example (where the IP addres is 198.51.100.43):

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 198.51.100.43
```

Comment: Yup, adding that server's IP to mynetworks resolved this problem.
Should I keep other config changes that I made above or is mynetworks entry sufficient for everything?

Comment: The `mynetworks` change is all you need. It's not necessary to put the IP address in `/etc/postfix/access`.

Comment: Under the right circumstances you do indeed need an access check in smtpd_sender_restrictions. It depends upon whether you have "permit_mynetworks" in smtpd_sender_restrictions and whether it comes before or after other checks.

Answer (score 7):

Right now, probably:

> ~ $ sudo postconf smtpd_sender_restrictions
>   smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain

Should be?

> ~ $ sudo postconf smtpd_sender_restrictions
>   smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access reject_unknown_sender_domain

option set in `main.cf`
You'll need to `postalias /etc/postfix/access` if you haven't already.

Also, chastise the sender for not owning the domain they're sending from (or not having had created the appropriate subdomain).

Comment: Before I resorted to modifying our mail config I fought long and hard with them to fix this problem on their end..Alas here I am. :(